# Read a image string from external file in android

Tags: java, android

i am making android application ..in which i have encoded my image string to external file in external card..But when i read that file to show image....application crashed..
here is a code:

```
storedpic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    ImageView storedimageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

    public void onClick(View v) {
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        File readfile = new File(sdcard, "myfile.txt");

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(readfile));
            String test;
            while (true) {
                test = br.readLine();
                // readLine() returns null if no more lines in the file
                byte[] bytarray = Base64.decode(test, Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap bmimage = BitmapFactory
                        .decodeByteArray(bytarray, 0, bytarray.length);
                storedimageView.setImageBitmap(bmimage);

                if (test == null)
                    break;

            }

        }

        catch (IOException e) {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Can't read a file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Crash details? OutOfMemory maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than likely [`Base64#decode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#decode%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) is  throwing an `NPE` as the input `String` is `null`. Try replacing

```
while (true) {
   test = br.readLine();
   ...
}
```

with

```
while ((test = br.readLine()) != null) {
   ...
}
```

Of course remove the `break` statement